# Running fab sanity gives an error: no module named quilt

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip, quilt

I an now setting up a work environment on some open source project I just cloned from GitHub,
after running

```
pip install -U -r requirements.txt
```

in a virtualenv of course, I was trying to run `fab sanity` as this projects uses fabric, and I am getting the following error:

```
(openmuni)oleg@oleg-Lenovo-G580:~/dev/openmuni-budgets$ fab sanity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 637, in main
    docstring, callables, default = load_fabfile(fabfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 164, in load_fabfile
    imported = importer(os.path.splitext(fabfile)[0])
  File "/home/oleg/dev/openmuni-budgets/fabfile/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from quilt import *
ImportError: No module named quilt
```

The most trivial 2 solutions didn't work unfortunately:

```
(openmuni)oleg@oleg-Lenovo-G580:~/dev/openmuni-budgets$ pip install quilt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): quilt in /home/oleg/.virtualenvs/openmuni/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Fabric>=1.8.0 in /home/oleg/.virtualenvs/openmuni/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from quilt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cuisine>=0.6.5 in /home/oleg/.virtualenvs/openmuni/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from quilt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko>=1.10.0 in /home/oleg/.virtualenvs/openmuni/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Fabric>=1.8.0->quilt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto>=2.1,!=2.4 in /home/oleg/.virtualenvs/openmuni/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=1.10.0->Fabric>=1.8.0->quilt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ecdsa in /home/oleg/.virtualenvs/openmuni/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=1.10.0->Fabric>=1.8.0->quilt)
Cleaning up...
```

---

```
(openmuni)oleg@oleg-Lenovo-G580:~/dev/openmuni-budgets$ pip install python-quilt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-quilt in /home/oleg/.virtualenvs/openmuni/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running:
`deavtivate`
and then
`pip install python-quilt` solved it, but that means that quilt is now global and installed outside of the virtualenv, a bit of a hack.